# Display first true and then false

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In my SQL table, I have records. Some of them have FLAG Y/N. Now, when I run my query, I want to display first all the Y values and then N.

**Table details**

**StuID   .... StuFlag**

1       .... N

2       .... N

3       .... Y

4       .... N

5       .... Y

Now, when I execute the query, the output should be:

3       .... Y

5       .... Y

1       .... N

2       .... N

4       .... N

Comment: ORDER BY StuFlag DESC ?

Comment: `ORDER BY (CASE StuFlag WHEN 'Y' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)`, or if you want to "cheat" `ORDER BY StuFlag DESC`, since `'Y' > 'N'` (but this is not as clear, or maintainable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean way would be:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  stuid  INTEGER NOT NULL ...
, stuflag BIT
, [.. OTHER COLUMNS .. ]
);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (42,TRUE);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (42,FALSE);

SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY stuflag DESC;
-- FALSE is less than TRUE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select StuID, StuFlag from table order by StuFlag desc
```

For more details, you can consult [The SQL ORDER BY Keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

Comment: Thank you for reply, The query I know but how to implement it with SP AND VIEW in SQL